# Why does my title in my browser starts with "Pages -"?

Tags: layouts

I have a public website in sharepoint 2010. The title of some pages in the browser starts with the prefix "Pages - here you see the title of the page". One of these pages is the home page http://mycompany.com/Pages/default.aspx. How can I remove this ugly unproffesional prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it by modifying the PlaceHolderPageTitle placeholder in your page layouts. You can make it 100% custom, or add something to the default browser title (PageTitle FieldValue).

[More details](http://www.topsharepoint.com/change-title-tag-on-sharepoint-sites)

Comment: I know this is old but... for some reason I keep seeing "Pages - TITLE":
<SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
 <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder></SharePoint:PageTitle>
According to the code it should only show the Title of the page, yet I keep seeing the "Page - " prefix, how can I remove that?